# Disable Dropdown on click of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a University menu, a radio button called View/Update Students and below is the dropdown value for radiobutton . The dropdown ID is students.
When i click on VTU university menu, I should be able to disable the students dropdown. I'm unable to do it. The student dropdown is in different JS and the code that I'm writing to disable is in differenr JS.
As per my understanding I can still use the #students from other JS . Please assist as I'm unable to disable select Dropdown.

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
     <li><a class="menu-a" id="university" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/univ/professor">VTU University</a></li>
   </ul>

</div>

$("#university").on("click", function(e){
        $("#students").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: Your anchor has an href which means when clicked the page is going to change/reload, check to see if that is what is happening. If it is stop it (preventDefault)

Comment: It goes to controller and displays the data that is required. I cannot stop it. Thats where the drodowns and other radio buttons are defined. How can i disable dropdowns on click of Menu ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `e.preventDefault();`  after `$("#students").prop("disabled", true);` to keep the paging from loading the href, but I don't see the point at all